# From one dimensional array must get multidimensional array based on keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Have array like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [CategoriesName_1] => Happy Birthday
        [CategoriesName_2] => Flowers
        [CategoriesName_3] => Fruit baskets
        [CategoriesDescription_1] => 
        [CategoriesDescription_2] => 
        [CategoriesDescription_3] => Fruit baskets descr
        [CategoriesUrl_1] => happy-birthday
        [CategoriesUrl_2] => flowers
        [CategoriesUrl_3] => fruit-baskets
    )

)
```

Want to convert it to array like this (need to get this result)

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [CategoriesName] => Happy Birthday
        [CategoriesDescription] => 
        [CategoriesUrl] => happy-birthday
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [CategoriesName] => Flowers
        [CategoriesDescription] => 
        [CategoriesUrl] => flowers
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [CategoriesName] => Fruit baskets
        [CategoriesDescription] => Fruit baskets descr
        [CategoriesUrl] => fruit-baskets
    )       

)
```

The initial (one dimensional array) have keys `CategoriesName_1`, `CategoriesUrl_1`, `CategoriesDescription_1`. For each number (`_1`, `_2`, `_3`) want to put name, url and description together and create separate subarray.

At first created 3 separate arrays

```
foreach ( $array_with_breadcrumbs[0] as $key_brcr => $val_brcr ) {

if( 'CategoriesUrl_' == substr($key_brcr,0,14) ){
$array_url_brcr[] = array( 'CategoriesUrl' => $val_brcr );
}

if( 'CategoriesName_' == substr($key_brcr,0,15) ){
$array_name_brcr[] = array( 'CategoriesName' => $val_brcr );
}

if( 'CategoriesDescription_' == substr($key_brcr,0,22) ){
$array_description_brcr[] = array( 'CategoriesDescription' => $val_brcr );
}

}//foreach ( $array_with_breadcrumbs[0] as $key_brcr => $val_brcr ) {
```

Then loop through all three arrays like this

```
foreach( $array_url_brcr as $i_url => $val_url ){

  foreach( $array_name_brcr as $i_name => $val_name ){

    foreach( $array_description_brcr as $i_description => $val_description ){

      if( $i_url == $i_name ) {

      $combined_arr_brcr[] = array( 
      'CategoriesUrl' => $val_url['CategoriesUrl'], 
      'CategoriesName' => $val_name['CategoriesName'], 
      'CategoriesDescription' => $val_description['CategoriesDescription']
      );

      }

    }

  }

}
```

I get nine (3 arrays * 3 loops) subarrays with not expected results. From the results I must write additional code where I take (keep) first, fifth and ninth subarray.

Code appears very long. Is there any better (shorter, simpler) way to get result?

Comment: How do You create first array?

Comment: First array from mysql 2 arr, then `array_replace_recursive`

Comment: So, Yours database structure looks like: CategoriesName_1, CategoriesName_2, CategoriesName_3 etc? And you get this data using `SELECT CategoriesName_1, CategoriesName_2, CategoriesName_3, ... FROM table`?

Comment: No, in database is `CategoriesName`, `CategoriesUrl`, etc. The initial array i get based on url. It is a long way (not reasonable to write here; too long code and not related with the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$final_array=array();
for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) { 
    $k=$i+1;
    $final_array[$i]=array(
        'CategoriesName'=>$array_with_breadcrumbs[0]['CategoriesName_'.$k],
        'CategoriesDescription'=>$array_with_breadcrumbs[0]['CategoriesDescription_'.$k],
        'CategoriesUrl'=>$array_with_breadcrumbs[0]['CategoriesUrl_'.$k],
        );
}

print_r($final_array);
```

if the number of keys is more than 3 , you can use this

```
$final_array=array();
$no_of_keys=3; //change the value of number of keys
$vars=array('CategoriesName','CategoriesDescription','CategoriesUrl'); // add variables

for ($i=0; $i < $no_of_keys; $i++) { 
    $k=$i+1;
    $final_array[$i]=array();
    foreach ($vars as $var) {
        $final_array[$i][$var]=$array_with_breadcrumbs[0][$var."_".$k]
    }
}

print_r($final_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$source = $array_with_breadcrumbs[0];
$result = [];

for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++)
{
    array_push($result,
    [
        'CategoriesName' => $source['CategoriesName_' . $i],
        'CategoriesDescription' => $source['CategoriesDescription_' . $i],
        'CategoriesUrl' => $source['CategoriesUrl_' . $i]
    ]);
}

var_dump($result);
```